# How do I access my sql server 2014 express adv from another computer?

Tags: sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2014-express

### Cannot connect to ITADMIN\SQL2014.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

Comment: Try reading through this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762257/connecting-to-a-2014-sqlexpress-database-on-an-externally-hosted-computer-throug